# how to get value of selected option using jquery

Tags: magento2, php, jquery

I need to get selected value from select field using jquery in magento

```
<field name="slider_location">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Modulename/js/form/element/containers</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Display On</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">slider_location</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Comment: i think your datatype must be select

Comment: i added `<item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply get it with the `select name attribute`

```
$('select[name=general[slider_location]]').val();
```

Note: **`general`** → is the **fieldset name**, change it accordingly.

You can bind the it on **`change`** event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select[name="slider_details[slider_location]"]').change(function(){
    alert( this.value );
  });
});
```

Comment: i added `jQuery('select[name=slider_details[slider_location]]').val();`  got a console error `syntax error, unrecognized expression: select[name=slider_details[slider_location]]`

Comment: try like `$('select[name="slider_details[slider_location]"]').val();`

Comment: i want to get value in initalize function there it is not working otherwise its working well

Comment: can you check updated answer